# How do I access an attribute of Parent class inside the child class? Doubts related to use of super()

Tags: python, oop, super

Here's a snippet of the code where the parent class is `Apparel`. `Apparel` has an attribute `__price`. I next define a class `Cotton` that inherits from class `Apparel`.
I use `super()` to invoke the parent methods.

```
class Apparel:
    def __init__(self,price,item_type):
        self.__price = price
        self.__item_type = item_type
    def calculate_price(self):
        self.__price = self.__price + 0.05*self.__price
```

Snippet of class `Cotton`:

```
class Cotton(Apparel):
    def __init__(self,price,discount):
        self.__discount = discount
        super().__init__(price,"Cotton")
    def calculate_price(self):
        super().calculate_price()
        self.__price = self.__price - self.__discount
    def get_price(self):
        return self.__price
```

Having invoked the parent method using `super()`, I expect that the attribute `__price` from the parent will be available to the child in that particular method. However, I get an error on running this:

```
c1 = Cotton(25000,2500)
c1.calculate_price()
print (c1.get_price())
```

And, the error is as follows:
AttributeError: 'Cotton' object has no attribute '_Cotton__price'

If it is due to name mangling, how to keep the attributes "super private" at the same time access the attributes in the child classes.
I tried several variations like trying to access `__price` by using `Apparel.__price` instead of `self.__price` in class `Cotton`, still does not work. Trying to check if am being silly somewhere, still can't figure out.

Comment: The attributes starting with `__` are name mangled in python to add the class name in front of them (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Python), use either single or no underscore to avoid this issue

Comment: There is no "super private" in Python. Name mangling transforms `__price` into `_Apparel__price` in the `Apparel` class, and into `_Cotton__price` in the `Cotton` class. While you *could* access those mangled names directly, so can whatever code you expect your private names to exclude from tinkering with your internals. Better to use a single underscore, which won't be mangled, but says to your users "This is intended to be private, and it is not part of the supported API".